# PipedReader.ready() does not throw exception when writer is already closed

Tags: java

I am using the method `ready()` of `PipedReader` to avoid blocking for input, but unfortunately if the writer has gone this method is not throwing an IOException (contrary to method `read()`, but this one is blocking).

What are the alternatives? Is there a non-blocking way to check that the writer has gone?

PS: I suppose this is a bug in `ready()`, because `read()` returns -1 when the writer has gone, but `ready()` keeps returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug in `ready()`. In `javadoc` it is said that `ready()` will not guarantee that next `read()` will be a block if it returns `false`. So -1 can be returned though `ready()` gives `false`.

It will throw an `IOException` only when the pipe is broken, unconnected, or closed. But I can't see a way to identify whether the connected `PipedWriter` is closed. Maybe you can use the result you are getting (-1) to identify. -1 will also say end of stream. But I see no different..

After all, why are you keep using these useless `PipedReaders`..??